# How do i make google docs pages to show in Bengali numbers?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-font-api, google-fonts, google-document-viewer

How do i make google docs to  show page numbers in Bengali numbers (১ ২ ৩ ৪)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the current state, Google Docs does not support Bengali Numbers for the numeration of the pages.

I recommend you to click `Help > Help Docs to Improve` and submit this as a Feature Request for Google Docs.